# docker, maven start failed: Connection is still allocated

Tags: maven, docker

i use a big project with maven + docker, all build war work fine , but i get a error when maven start last task:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.18.1:start > (start) on project mnm-docker: Execution start of goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.18.1:start failed: Connection is still allocated -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
>   [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :mnm-docker

i can not find any in google search about **start failed: Connection is still allocated**
All port exposed are not used in my window 10

any have some idea?before reinstall window, all worked fine

Comment: Could you post the snippet of fabric8 plugin ? Could you also run again with -X and -e switch ?

Comment: It is different on window 10 home and Pro version. I have added a  solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226315/failed-to-execute-fabric8-docker-plugin/46598043#46598043 

May be above help you

Answer (score 1):

**resolved**
ping localhost not resolve 127.0.0.1

i have changed the DOCKER_HOST with ip **127.0.0.1**

```
set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
```